# Password policy configuration using XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, xml-parsing, passwords

How to create and configure password policy using XML in spring.
I want to create different passwords validation using xml and want to apply specific validation as user wants?

Comment: Did you already create any configuration? If so, please show it.

Comment: no i have not create any configuration xml for password, i did configuration for only for rest API and hibernate in spring.I got some reference from this :https://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/18589.html

Answer (score 0):

1. User accesses a URL on a web application
2. The web application refers to web.xml
3. The web.xml matches the URL pattern
4. The control is redirected to DispatcherServlet in Spring framework
5. Spring framework finds that the all URLs are secured and hence displays login page to the user
6. The user enters his login name and password
7. Spring framework validates the login name and password by using the entries in Spring configuration XML and redirects to the accessed original URL

> **For complete method refer here:**http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-security-using-xml/

Comment: i want  this type of configuration <ComplexityPolicies> 
  <Policy> 
    <RuleSet> 
  <Rule MinPwdLen="6"/>
      <Rule MinNumeric="1"/> 
      <Rule MinSpecial="1"/> 
    </RuleSet> 
  </Policy> 
  <Policy> 
    <RuleSet> 
  <Rule MinPwdLen="6"/>
      <Rule MinNumeric="2"/> 
    </RuleSet> 
  </Policy> 
  <Policy> 
    <RuleSet> 
  <Rule MinPwdLen="6"/>
      <Rule MinSpecial="2"/> 
    </RuleSet> 
  </Policy> 
 </ComplexityPolicies>